# Script won't stop sending emails

Tags: google-apps-script

Below is my script. It sends emails, as its suppose to, but it continues to send emails even when the refereed cell already says "Sent". Can anyone show me where I went wrong?

```html
 
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,13);
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var employeeName = data [i][6];
    var startDate = data [i][2];
    var endDate = data [i][3];
    var oHours = data [i][4];
    var email = data [i][14];
    var emailAd = data [i][1];
    var response = data [i][9];
    if (response == "Approved" && email != "Sent"){
      var subject = "Overtime Request";
      var message = "Your request for overtime for " + employeeName + " has been " + response + ". This overtime should occur between " + startDate + " to " + endDate + " and should not exceed " + oHours + " hours.";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAd,subject,message);
      sheet.getRange(i+2,14).setValue("Sent");}
    else if(response=="Declined" && email != "Sent"){
        var subject = "Overtime Request";
      var message = "Your request for overtime for " + employeeName + " has been " + response + ".";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAd,subject,message); 
      sheet.getRange(i+2,14).setValue("Sent");}
    else if(email == "Sent"){return;}
  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the `email` is `undefined` and `email != "Sent"` will always evaluate to true.

At this line:

```
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,13);
```

The [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns) method is getting the the columns A to M, and then at this line:

```
var email = data [i][14];
```

You're trying to get the value of the column O.

> Remember that while a range index starts at 1, 1, the JavaScript array
>   will be indexed from [0][0].

You just need to change your `sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,13);` to `sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,15);` so you can get the value where you're setting the value `"Sent"` and evaluate it in your `if()` statement.

Comment: You are a God send. Thank you so much. I spent way to much time on that today trying to figure it out. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.